# How to extract specific files from current version and merge it with the baseline version+SVN

Tags: svn

This is a quick Question on SVN repository do how.
We have 3 different changes going Live on 3 different dates in a single branch (3 changes are in 3 different files) .
Now we decided to make 3 single branch containing codes for 3 different Go Live dates so that it becomes easy to roll out the specific changes to Production.

We intend to take the first changes expected on the earliest Go Live Date(say April2016 ) and want to merge it with the baseline trunk version in SVN and make a April2016 branch.
What is the easiest way to do that ? Any idea is Greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create `April2016` from trunk
- Cherry pick `GoLiveApril2016` revision to `April2016` branch